# Pip-v showing python 310 fatal error. But I've python 3.11.2

Tags: python, variables, pip, environment

[Fatal error in launcher](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eRYU0.png)

I did try tinkering with the environment variables. But couldn't solve the problem. Please help.

Comment: Your `pip` installation uses Python 3.10, not whatever Python is first in your path.

Comment: Ideally, you'll only pip-install code in a virtual environment where compatible `pip` and `python` binaries are installed together. But if you want to use `pip` outside a virtual environment, I recommend using `PYTHON -m pip ...`, where `PYTHON` is the `python` provided by the installation you want to interact with.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.